# Leveraging CustomMultiChildLayout to create a cluster of Circular Avatar's similar to Group iMessage UI

Tags: flutter

Could someone with experience [`CustomMultiChildLayout`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) help with creating this complex UI that is used to display all the profile pictures in an iMessage group?

I've been playing around with [`CustomMultiChildLayout`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) but am struggling to get this layout.

I'm also wondering if there's an algorithmic way to generate this the way Apple does it or if I'd be better off hardcoding each variation from like 1-20 avatars.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you tell how it looks with 50/200 members?  Is it scrollable? Is there a max limit? anything.

Comment: @Rahul for this let's just say 10 people is maximum.  The cases of lots are not needed but im more just trying to achieve the general UI

Comment: and what problems do you have with the [delegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout/delegate.html) class?

Comment: @pskink no errors but im not able to recreate the UI